# Getting param value in lower case only - PHP phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I am passing some params in url as below:

```
sample/team/highestScore/1
```

My router code for accepting this URL is:

```
$this->add('/sample/team/{tab:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+}/{matchType:[0-9]+}',array('action' => 'teamAction'))->setName('sample');
```

But in controller I am getting the value of param '**tab**' as **highestscore**, means in lowercase. I need the param value as **highestScore**. How can I get the value without case conversion.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

#### Controller: (app/controllers/someController.php)

```php
function teamAction($tab = null, $matchType = null)
{
    exit(var_dump([
        $tab,
        $matchType
    ]));
}
```

#### route ( app/config/router.php )

```php
$router = $di->getRouter();

$router->add(
    '/sample/team/{tab:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+}/{matchType:[0-9]+}',
    [
        'controller' => 'some',
        'action'     => 'team'
    ]
);

$router->handle();
```

testing url `phalcon_path/sample/team/highestScore/1`

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'highestScore' (length=12)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
```